# Difference between React element and Browser DOM element

Tags: reactjs, dom

Browser DOM elements are something that we see on screen and the same goes true for React elements. They both can have classes. The only distinction as far as I understand is that the Browser DOM element is handled by Browser DOM but React element is handled by React Virtual DOM. Although there are some syntactical differences. Apart from that what makes React element different from the Browser DOM element?

Answer (score 0):

React controls how and when it will update the actual dom.
Another difference is updating the virtual dom is more efficient than updating the actual dom.

This process is called reconciliation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: That’s what I already said React has virtual DOM unlike browser DOM. I’m looking for difference between React element and Browser DOM element. Well thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

HTML elements are standardized and depending on the type of element sometimes semantic. They are understood by software such as crawlers, robots, screen readers, browser extensions. plugins and assistive software.

React JSX elements are parsed and deconstructed into JavaScript code at compile time.

Example the React JSX markup:

```html
<Hello toWhat="World" />
```

Gets compiled into:

```js
React.createElement(Hello, {toWhat: 'World'}, null)
```

Comment: Does that mean that JSX are kind of injected compiled JavaScript in component? One distinction I can think of now is that we can even create our own React element .So does that mean that react element have no semantic meaning.

Comment: The React element has no semantic meaning because it is a custom non-standard element. JSX is markup language invented by React which are processed and transformed at compile time into JavaScript. I don't know exactly how React pushes those into the DOM or virtual DOM.